# Which $\Bbb{Z}_p-$ extension satisfies assumption of Washington's book Prop13.22?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

In iwasawa theory, we often suppose $\Bbb{Z}_p-$ extension satisfies the following condition.

・Exactly one prime is ramified

・And the prime is totally ramified

Which $\Bbb{Z}_p-$ extension satisfies this two condition ?
In particular ,I want to know the reason why $\Bbb{Z}_p-$ extension over $\Bbb{Q}(ζ_p)$ satisfies the condition.
Thank you in advance.

Back ground: I want to check iwasawa class formula holds for some $\Bbb{Z}_p-$ extension, and Washington's book 'Introduction to cyclotomic fields',$Prop13.22$ supposes above two assumption, if I could check this assumption, I will be able to check iwasawa class number formula for that field.

Comment: You perhaps mean $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})=\cup_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$.

Comment: What is your ground field?

Comment: The main ground field is $ \Bbb{Q(ζ_p})$. I also wonder why the case of ground field is $\Bbb{Q}$ does not satisfy the two assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to see that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q}$ is ramified only at $p$ where it is totally ramified, and that for $p$ odd its Galois group is $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times \cong C_{p-1}\times \Bbb{Z}_p$ (for $p=2$ it is  $\Bbb{Z}_2^\times \cong C_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2$), so
$$\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p) \text{ and }
\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})^H/\Bbb{Q}$$
both satisfy the requirements, where $H= \{ h_a: \zeta_{p^n}\mapsto \zeta_{p^n}^{a^{p^n}}, a\in 1\ldots p-1\}$ for $p$ odd (for $p=2$ it is $H= \{ h_a: \zeta_{p^n}\mapsto \zeta_{p^n}^a, a=\pm 1\}$)

Comment: In which ground field $K$, the requirement does not hold?

Comment: Any number field having more than one prime above $p$